# Azure Function not triggering every 3 hours as stated in the cron expression

Tags: azure, function, triggers, azure-functions

I deployed an azure function that should execute every 3 hours. In the settings on the portal for the function I could indeed see it says: `0 0 */3 * * *`

However at 9AM, 12PM and, 3PM nothing has fired. In App insights in Azure it says:

```
The next 5 occurrences of the 'IAmAlive' schedule (Cron: '0 0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * *') will be:
12/18/2020 03:00:00Z
12/18/2020 06:00:00Z
12/18/2020 09:00:00Z
12/18/2020 12:00:00Z
12/18/2020 15:00:00Z
```

Any mention of it was last seen yesterday at 9:20Pm stating what i pasted above
[image]

Any insight on why it possibly is not running?

Comment: You might want to check if it actually doesn't run, or just doesn't have anything to do? Is the rest of the Function OK? _Can_ it run? You can go to the Function App in the Azure Portal, Open up the Functions blade, select the Function you would expect to run and open up 'Monitor'. You can see all invocations there.

Comment: 1) Check function is enabled (or someone has disabled it). 2) if enable, click on the function and go to Monitor and check the logs of last run. From there you can open the application insights query too.